# What is actually inside navigationController's "view" property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I was going through Apple's documentation about navigation controller and find this point ambiguous and hard to comprehend.

It was written in this [online documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html) of navigation controller.

> Navigation Controller Views
>
> A navigation controller is a container view controller—that is, it
>   embeds the content of other view controllers inside of itself. You
>   access a navigation controller’s view from its view property. This
>   view incorporates the navigation bar, an optional toolbar, and the
>   content view corresponding to the topmost view controller. Figure 2
>   shows how these views are assembled to present the overall navigation
>   interface. (In this figure, the navigation interface is further
>   embedded inside a tab bar interface.) Although the content of the
>   navigation bar and toolbar views changes, the views themselves do not.
>   The only view that actually changes is the custom content view
>   provided by the topmost view controller on the navigation stack.

From that, my understanding is that inside this "view" property. There should be at least two subview inside this view.One is the navigationBar the other is the contentView of the current displayed viewController’s view. But while I am debugging only the navigation bar showed with another view called UINavigationTransitionView showed.

[image]

My question is, is this normal. Have I done anything wrong?

Second, what is the most common way to access current displayed viewController's view with only the reference to the navigation controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationTransitionView controller contains one wrapper view which intern will have the current uiviewcontroller's view.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find this view as a subview of UINavigationTransitionView. However this is not the "right" way to do this. The proper way is to go through property "topViewController" and then take its view:

```
    self.navigationController.topViewController.view
```

If there is another view controller or its view that you need, you have access to whole view controller's hierarchy across navigation controller through viewControllers property.

```
    self.navigationController.viewControllers
```

More here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html